# How to fix 503 error with resize image lambda edge functions on cloudfront?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, aws-lambda-edge

I am trying resize images with a cloudfront distribution accoring to article : https://aws.amazon.com/tr/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/resizing-images-with-amazon-cloudfront-lambdaedge-aws-cdn-blog/

I created project folder with given Origin-Response and Viewer-Request functions on article and I downloaded dependencies, deployed the zip package  with cloudformation template.

IAM Role, s3 bucket, bucket policy, distribution with lambda@edge functions were created without any error and they all seem compatible.

But I get the error below when I try to resize an image in the origin bucket;

"503 ERROR
The request could not be satisfied.
The Lambda function associated with the CloudFront distribution is invalid or doesn't have the required permissions. "

I also don't see anything on monitoring which means my functions are not invoked.

I created another admin role with "AdministratorAccess" policy and trust relationships The "edgelambda.amazonaws.com","lambda.amazonaws.com"

I change my bucket policy to all public.

I could view the image but I still get 503 error when I try to resize with adding querystring to cloudfront distribution url

"xxxxxxxxx.net/images/pexels.jpeg?d=100x100"

Here are my bucket, bucket policy, IAM Roles and functions.

Bucket name : image-resize-488052071209-us-east-1

Bukcet policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::image-resize-488052071209-us-east-1/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::image-resize-488052071209-us-east-1/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::image-resize-488052071209-us-east-1/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

IAM Roles:

```
Admin:
AdministratorAccess, "edgelambda.amazonaws.com","lambda.amazonaws.com" trust relationships

ImageFunctionsAndRole-EdgeLambdaRole-1U93T440VWXKT:
AmazonS3FullAccess, CloudFrontFullAccess, AWSLambdaExecute, CloudFrontReadOnlyAccess, AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
```

Viewer-Request Function

```
'use strict';

const querystring = require('querystring');

// defines the allowed dimensions, default dimensions and how much variance from allowed
// dimension is allowed.

const variables = {
        allowedDimension : [ {w:100,h:100}, {w:200,h:200}, {w:300,h:300}, {w:400,h:400} ],
        defaultDimension : {w:200,h:200},
        variance: 20,
        webpExtension: 'webp'
  };

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
    const headers = request.headers;

    // parse the querystrings key-value pairs. In our case it would be d=100x100
    const params = querystring.parse(request.querystring);

    // fetch the uri of original image
    let fwdUri = request.uri;

    // if there is no dimension attribute, just pass the request
    if(!params.d){
        callback(null, request);
        return;
    }
    // read the dimension parameter value = width x height and split it by 'x'
    const dimensionMatch = params.d.split("x");

    // set the width and height parameters
    let width = dimensionMatch[0];
    let height = dimensionMatch[1];

    // parse the prefix, image name and extension from the uri.
    // In our case /images/image.jpg

    const match = fwdUri.match(/(.*)\/(.*)\.(.*)/);

    let prefix = match[1];
    let imageName = match[2];
    let extension = match[3];

    // define variable to be set to true if requested dimension is allowed.
    let matchFound = false;

    // calculate the acceptable variance. If image dimension is 105 and is within acceptable
    // range, then in our case, the dimension would be corrected to 100.
    let variancePercent = (variables.variance/100);

    for (let dimension of variables.allowedDimension) {
        let minWidth = dimension.w - (dimension.w * variancePercent);
        let maxWidth = dimension.w + (dimension.w * variancePercent);
        if(width >= minWidth && width <= maxWidth){
            width = dimension.w;
            height = dimension.h;
            matchFound = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    // if no match is found from allowed dimension with variance then set to default
    //dimensions.
    if(!matchFound){
        width = variables.defaultDimension.w;
        height = variables.defaultDimension.h;
    }

    // read the accept header to determine if webP is supported.
    let accept = headers['accept']?headers['accept'][0].value:"";

    let url = [];
    // build the new uri to be forwarded upstream
    url.push(prefix);
    url.push(width+"x"+height);

    // check support for webp
    if (accept.includes(variables.webpExtension)) {
        url.push(variables.webpExtension);
    }
    else{
        url.push(extension);
    }
    url.push(imageName+"."+extension);

    fwdUri = url.join("/");

    // final modified url is of format /images/200x200/webp/image.jpg
    request.uri = fwdUri;
    callback(null, request);
};
```

Origin-Response Function:

```
'use strict';

const http = require('http');
const https = require('https');
const querystring = require('querystring');

const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const S3 = new AWS.S3({
  signatureVersion: 'v4',
});
const Sharp = require('sharp');

// set the S3 and API GW endpoints
const BUCKET = 'image-resize-${AWS::AccountId}-us-east-1';

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  let response = event.Records[0].cf.response;

  console.log("Response status code :%s", response.status);

  //check if image is not present
  if (response.status == 404) {

    let request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
    let params = querystring.parse(request.querystring);

    // if there is no dimension attribute, just pass the response
    if (!params.d) {
      callback(null, response);
      return;
    }

    // read the dimension parameter value = width x height and split it by 'x'
    let dimensionMatch = params.d.split("x");

    // read the required path. Ex: uri /images/100x100/webp/image.jpg
    let path = request.uri;

    // read the S3 key from the path variable.
    // Ex: path variable /images/100x100/webp/image.jpg
    let key = path.substring(1);

    // parse the prefix, width, height and image name
    // Ex: key=images/200x200/webp/image.jpg
    let prefix, originalKey, match, width, height, requiredFormat, imageName;
    let startIndex;

    try {
      match = key.match(/(.*)\/(\d+)x(\d+)\/(.*)\/(.*)/);
      prefix = match[1];
      width = parseInt(match[2], 10);
      height = parseInt(match[3], 10);

      // correction for jpg required for 'Sharp'
      requiredFormat = match[4] == "jpg" ? "jpeg" : match[4];
      imageName = match[5];
      originalKey = prefix + "/" + imageName;
    }
    catch (err) {
      // no prefix exist for image..
      console.log("no prefix present..");
      match = key.match(/(\d+)x(\d+)\/(.*)\/(.*)/);
      width = parseInt(match[1], 10);
      height = parseInt(match[2], 10);

      // correction for jpg required for 'Sharp'
      requiredFormat = match[3] == "jpg" ? "jpeg" : match[3]; 
      imageName = match[4];
      originalKey = imageName;
    }

    // get the source image file
    S3.getObject({ Bucket: BUCKET, Key: originalKey }).promise()
      // perform the resize operation
      .then(data => Sharp(data.Body)
        .resize(width, height)
        .toFormat(requiredFormat)
        .toBuffer()
      )
      .then(buffer => {
        // save the resized object to S3 bucket with appropriate object key.
        S3.putObject({
            Body: buffer,
            Bucket: BUCKET,
            ContentType: 'image/' + requiredFormat,
            CacheControl: 'max-age=31536000',
            Key: key,
            StorageClass: 'STANDARD'
        }).promise()
        // even if there is exception in saving the object we send back the generated
        // image back to viewer below
        .catch(() => { console.log("Exception while writing resized image to bucket")});

        // generate a binary response with resized image
        response.status = 200;
        response.body = buffer.toString('base64');
        response.bodyEncoding = 'base64';
        response.headers['content-type'] = [{ key: 'Content-Type', value: 'image/' + requiredFormat }];
        callback(null, response);
      })
    .catch( err => {
      console.log("Exception while reading source image :%j",err);
    });
  } // end of if block checking response statusCode
  else {
    // allow the response to pass through
    callback(null, response);
  }
};
```

Comment: Does CloudWatch logs say anything about the execution ? You need to see the logs and CW metrics in region closer to where request hitting the edge location, you create the lambda in us-east-1 but it gets replicated (read only) to all the regions.

Comment: No I don't see anything on cloudwatch logs :( I know this means my function is not invoked, thinking that I checked with roles but they have lambdaexecution and cloudwatch log policies

Comment: Your logs might be in another region, please check this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-edge-testing-debugging.html#lambda-edge-testing-debugging-determine-region

Comment: Also can you confirm that the execution role **associated** with your function has the correct trusted entities? You can check this in the Lambda console by clicking on the key icon and looking at *Execution Role*.

Comment: Hello, yes trusted entities are : Trusted entities
The identity provider(s) lambda.amazonaws.com
The identity provider(s) edgelambda.amazonaws.com

Comment: Hello  @jogold I cant seem to troubleshoot logs even withaws cli steps right now but thats ot the error anymore. It turned into an "AccessDenied" error when I use querystring.  And I know functions work because when I deployed functions to another bucket they resized images however i want. Please help!!

Comment: correction : another bucket's distribution.  I can view images but I can not resize them with querystring like ?d=100x100 I get "AccessDenied"

Comment: @cansu.asci I'm facing the same issue! Did you find a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I followed the same blog post and hit the same issues, which I've been battling for several hours. I now have a working solution so thought I'd share my setup.

I didn't use CloudFormation, and instead created the resources manually.

The first change from the article required is in the `origin-response/index.js` script. AWS returns a `403` status for non existant files, so the line which checks `if (response.status == 404) {` needs changing to the below:

```js
if (response.status == 404 || response.status == 403) {
```

The next change I made was on the `AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole` policy. Because the Lambda function can run in multiple regions, it writes logs to CloudWatch in multiple regions. So I changed the Resource ARN to wildcard the region. Below is the Policy JSON:

```js
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Next up I made sure that the Bucket Policy allowed access to the Lambda role and CloudFront:

```js
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXXX:role/service-role/image-resize-origin-response-role-XXXXXXXXX"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

The last piece of the puzzle was creating a policy for the same Lambda role to work with the S3 Bucket:

```js
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME/*"
        }
    ]
}
```